# Munit 2 - trying to test a simple GET endpoint by comparing response containing correlationId

Tags: mule, mule4, munit

Using Mule 4 and have a GET endpoint : `getEmployee`
The API I am trying to MUNIT is an experience api and its expected response is :

```
{
   
    "correlationId": correlationId  ( Mule correlation id ),
    "empDetails" : {
       "ename": "John",
       "eid": "100" 
    }
}
```

In the above response, data received from process api is set against `empDetails`.The experience api is adding correlationId in response.

The problem I am encountering is when trying to Munit this endpoint . I am mocking the process api response
So the mocked response is a static json file :

```
{
       "ename": "John",
       "eid": "100"
    }
```

Once this mocked response ( from process api ) is received back in experience api , we append correlation id before sending response back.

So in My Munit I am trying to compare results from runtime with a static response from a json file.
My static response in json file is as below :

```
    {

    "correlationId": "abcd",
    "empDetails" : {
       "ename": "John",
       "eid": "100" 
    }
}
```

Notice that above in static json file the correlation id is expected to be `abcd`

So in my munit I am trying to set correlation id with `abcd` :

```
   <munit:set-event doc:name="Set Event">
    <munit:attributes value="#[{ method : 'GET',  requestPath: '/employee', headers : { 'X- 
    CORRELATION-ID' : 'abcd'}}]" />
    ...
    ...
```

However inspite of setting the correlationid header value to a fixed static value `abcd` , mule runtime is dynamically generating the value and as a result rather than having `abcd` in response we are getting a dynamic value causing munit to fail ...

Note - when I run the api and invoke this endpoint via postman , then whatever value i send in header `X-Correlation-Id` is being set against correlationid ( expected behaviour )

However in case of munit this is not happening .

I think the difference between the two is - in actual run - the HTTP listener is invoked Vs in case of Munit the specific flow is being tested ( after http listener and api kit router ) , so I am suspecting this is why mule is already setting correlation id in case of munit.

So really I need some way to control the value of correlationid in Munit , how do we achieve the same ?

Comment: Please share versions of Mule and MUnit, and the actual test case including the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to control the correlationId in your situation:

1. Use the Tracing module in the MUnit execution scope

```
    <munit:execution>
        <tracing:with-correlation-id correlationId='#["abcd"]'>
            <!-- invoke flow here -->
        </tracing-with-correlation-id>
    </munit:execution>
```

2. Initiate the flow from your MUnit execution scope using the HTTP Requester and set the `correlationId` attribute to your intended value.  Here you have to include both your APIKit main flow and your specific route flow in your `enableFlowSources` list for the MUnit test.

Comment: The Tracing Module depends on a feature released with Mule 4.4 and will not work with previous versions.